# Contact form 7 conditional fields only work in admin

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact form 7 conditional fields and i have a weird problem. The forms only work well in admin mode, but when send a form logged off, some fields are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess, please check if you put the `subscribers_only: true` in the admin mode. make it **FALSE**.

Comment: I try it. But i solved the problem. It was the cache system. Desactive the cache solved the problem!